# Python multiprocessing Queue put() behavior

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I'm doing something very simple using multiprocessing:

```
data = {'a': 1}
queue.put(data, True)
data.clear()
```

When I use the queue on another process (using `get()` method), I get an empty dictionary. If I remove `data.clear()` I get the keys as expected. Is there any way to wait for the `put()` to have finished the serialization ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, this is thought to be a feature, not a problem.
The queue immediately returns so your process continues while serialization happens and to avoid what is known as "[queue contention](http://bugs.python.org/issue17025)".

The two options I suggest you have:

1. Are you absolutely sure you need mutable dictionaries in the first place? Instead of making defensive copies of your data, which you correctly seem to dislike, why not just create a new dictionary instead of using `dict.clear()` and let the garbage collector worry about old dictionaries?
2. Pickle the data yourself; That is: `a_queue.put(pickle.dumps(data))` and `pickle.loads(a_queue.get())`. Now, if you do `data.clear()` just after a `put`, the data has already been serialized "by you".

From a parallel programming point of view the first approach (treat your data as if it were immutable) is the more viable and clean thing to do on the long term, but I am not sure if or why you must clear your dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the option 1 is absolutely the most elegant since the time to copy the data is by far greater than the time to create a new dictionary and let GC handle it.

Comment: This is literally a "its not a bug, it's a feature!" moment in python

Comment: I will humbly disagree. If I hand you data and you need access to it afterwards, it's your responsibility to make a copy. At least now I know what went wrong.

Answer (score 4):

The best way is probably to make a copy of `data` before sending it. Try:

```
data = {'a': 1}
dc = data.copy()
queue.put(dc)
data.clear()
```

Basically, you can't count on the send finishing before the dictionary is cleared, so you shouldn't try. `dc` will be garbage-collected when it goes out of scope or when the code is executed again.

Comment: This is what I'm doing now as a workaround, but I don't want extra copies just to make sure the serialization will actually take place at right moment.